# WPF ComboBox culture not being applied to values

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box which is bound to a collection of doubles via a converter, which is just used to locate the collection from the name of an associated property. The combo box is in a DataTemplate for a Property Grid editor. The problem is that the combo box does not display the values in the current system culture (i.e. using a ',' as a decimal separator, rather than a '.'). All other properties in the Property Grid are displayed correctly (e.g. in text boxes).

The DataTemplate looks something like this, and the ListComboBoxValuesConverter just returns a collection of doubles.

```
<ComboBox 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ListComboBoxValuesConverter},
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type propgrid:IPropertyDataAccessor}}}"
   Text="{Binding Path=Value,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type propgrid:IPropertyDataAccessor}}, 
        Mode=TwoWay,
        ValidatesOnExceptions=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
</ComboBox>
```

Thanks

Edit:

The solution I've come up with is to set the item template for the combo box and use a converter to return the value as a correctly formatted string. It feels like this should be unnecessary, but there you go!

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource FloatValueCultureConverter}, ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem could be on the converter, try returning the toString using the CultureInfo passed as parameter to the converter (converter from double to string):

```
return someDouble.ToString(culture);
```

Comment: The converter returns the entire collection of doubles, not each one separately. I suppose the converter could return them as a collection of strings if needed, but it seems like the combo box should know how to display the doubles in the correct culture.

Comment: Ok, then try to return a list of strings and foreach one make the .ToString(culture). Check if this works, i think the culture must be set on the binding. If you define a binding you are replacing the default binding.

Comment: Thanks, this did work, but because the converter is returning a list, when the list changes this is not observed in the combo box, without closing an reopening the view. I've done something similar using an item template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Language attribute on the ComboBox or on any containing element to the current culture's ietf-Tag. If you want to respect customizations of the user's locale, you have to set the Binding's ConverterCulture to the currentuiculture. You can find details on this topic in [Localized Value Formatting in WPF](http://wpfglue.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/localized-value-formatting-in-wpf/).